# Formatting a Double Precision to 'MI:SS' in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, datetime, average

I am running an average on a column in my table that produces a double precision number as seconds.  I need to format that output to 'MI:SS'.

```
SELECT
     AVG(td.talktime) AS avg_talk_time
FROM
     talk_data td
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Better to put some more details, what did you try already and what results did you get? You should have tried something before asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use arithmetics and string functions:

```
select floor(avg(talktime)/60) 
    || ':' 
    || lpad((avg(talktime) % 60)::text, 2, '0') as avg_talk_time 
from talk_data
```

Or better yet in Postgres, you can use intervals:

```
select avg(talktime) * '1 second'::interval as avg_talk_time 
from talk_data
```

Note that both queries do not produce the same resultset: say the average is 3601, the first query gives `60:01`, while the second returns `1:00:01`.